# return Identity in SQLServer Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, identity-column

How do you get the identity column value after an insert in SQL Server Compact 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is @@IDENTITY:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS Identity
```

This will return the value of the last identity inserted.

Comment: I didn't think SSCE supports sql batch statements, will have to check

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to use [@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077.aspx).  I figured compact would have [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), but I guess not.  Just try scope_identity to be sure. :)

Comment: I didn't think SSCE supports sql batch statements, will have to check

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
SELECT MAX(<IdentityColumn>) FROM <TableName>
```